# Adding my animation to my playable character

Tags: ios, animation, view

Ok , the following code is in my character .m file and is code for an animation that I want to run when my game starts so that the character you can play as animates through 4 images.

```
-(void) Animate {

    UIImage* img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Obstacle.png"];
    UIImage* img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Obstacle02.png"];
    UIImage* img3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Obstacle03.png"];
    UIImage* img4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Obstacle04.png"];

    NSArray *animateArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:img1,img2,img3,img4, nil];

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 160)];

    self.imageView.animationImages = animateArray;

    self.imageView.animationDuration = 0.5;

    [self.imageView startAnimating];

    self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;

    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];

}
```

but I am dumbfounded at how I should add this sequence to my actual character view ( the playable character ) . Ive had a go at it you can see the [self.view addSubview:self.imageView]; but that code was provided to me in a previous question and I dont understand it . If someone could help , that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line adds the image view to a `UIView` subclass. If this class is your character's view then you're going to see the animation positioned at the given frame when this function is invoked.

Comment: thing is im not sure what is the characters view

Comment: The code belongs there if you want it to perform as described